# vodacom webbook ubuntu ON9 v1.13.3

Tags: unity

I need help I have lost my password for my ubuntu v1.13.3 and I don't knw how to reset it I have tried  writting 'mount/dev/mmcblk0p3/mnt'after builts in command list but it shows no found